# cannot collapse navbar using selenium through device on browserstack

Tags: java, selenium, hybrid-mobile-app, browserstack

I am trying to do some device testing via browserstack but I'm having a few issues. My bigest blocker at this time is that I cannot for the life of me see how I click on a drop-down for the mobile collapsible navbar.  I am using the same csslocator that i use in some other mobile tests on Cypress but here it doesn't seem to work.  In browserstack it says it clicked on the element but the video playback doesn't show the navbar collapse and therefore i cannot click on any of the links in the navbar drop-down.

Presently I am trying:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.card-title.h5")));

driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector(".app-main-nav > .app-navbar.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-dark > button > i")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#nav-collapse > div.ml-auto.navbar-nav")));

driverSafari.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-collapse > div.ml-auto.navbar-nav > div:nth-child(2) > a")).click();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated as this is driving me nuts!

The above code was for Apple iOS XS but the same code works for Android.

This dom is as follows:

```
<nav class="app-navbar navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
   <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/static/WEB0046_GL-Logo_November_19_240x70-ba2887d7333e74c970dc3c4aafc9b5d3.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand-logo"></a><button aria-controls="nav-collapse" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler collapsed"><img src="/static/WEB0046_GL-Logo_Mobile_-_November_19_300x300-48e01512add8e785e9334eedf8b27902.png" alt="" class="navbar-brand-logo-mobile"><i class="chevron-icon"><span class="sp-1"></span><span class="sp-2"></span></i></button>
   <div class="club-link-mobile nav-item">
      <div class="nav-item">
         <div class="fav-clubs-menu dropdown">
            <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdown-basic" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
               <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg-inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16 " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                  <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
               </svg>
               <span class="fav-clubs-num">1</span><span class="fav-clubs-text">club</span><i class="down"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav-collapse">
      <div class="ml-auto navbar-nav">
         <div class=" home-link-mobile undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="/" data-rb-event-key="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></div>
         <div class="  undefined nav-item">
            <a target="_self" href="/find-a-class/" data-rb-event-key="/find-a-class/" class="nav-link">
               <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="clipboard-list" class="svg-inline--fa fa-clipboard-list fa-w-12 navicon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
                  <path fill="currentColor" d="M336 64h-80c0-35.3-28.7-64-64-64s-64 28.7-64 64H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h288c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V112c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM96 424c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24 24 10.7 24 24-10.7 24-24 24zm0-96c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24 24 10.7 24 24-10.7 24-24 24zm0-96c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24 24 10.7 24 24-10.7 24-24 24zm96-192c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.7 24-24 24-24-10.7-24-24 10.7-24 24-24zm128 368c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H168c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-96c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H168c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16zm0-96c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8H168c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8v-16c0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8h144c4.4 0 8 3.6 8 8v16z"></path>
               </svg>
               Find a class
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="  undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="/find-a-club/" data-rb-event-key="/find-a-club/" class="nav-link">Club</a></div>
         <div class="  undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="/challenges/" data-rb-event-key="/challenges/" class="nav-link">Challenges</a></div>
         <div class="  undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="/memberships/" data-rb-event-key="/memberships/" class="nav-link">Memberships</a></div>
         <div class="btn-nav  undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="https://www.goodlifehealthclubs.com.au/" data-rb-event-key="https://www.goodlifehealthclubs.com.au/" class="nav-link">Join now</a></div>
         <div class=" home-link-mobile undefined nav-item"><a target="_self" href="/free-trial" data-rb-event-key="/free-trial" class="nav-link">Get a 5 day free pass</a></div>
         <div class="club-header-nav">
            <div class="nav-item">
               <div class="fav-clubs-menu dropdown">
                  <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdown-basic" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                     <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg-inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16 " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
                     </svg>
                     <span class="fav-clubs-num">1</span><span class="fav-clubs-text">club</span><i class="down"></i>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-contact">
         <p class="navbar-contact-label">Have a question or need help?</p>
         <a href="tel:1300 393 733" target="_self" class="navbar-contact-link">
            <i>
               <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="phone" class="svg-inline--fa fa-phone fa-w-16 phone-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                  <path fill="currentColor" d="M493.4 24.6l-104-24c-11.3-2.6-22.9 3.3-27.5 13.9l-48 112c-4.2 9.8-1.4 21.3 6.9 28l60.6 49.6c-36 76.7-98.9 140.5-177.2 177.2l-49.6-60.6c-6.8-8.3-18.2-11.1-28-6.9l-112 48C3.9 366.5-2 378.1.6 389.4l24 104C27.1 504.2 36.7 512 48 512c256.1 0 464-207.5 464-464 0-11.2-7.7-20.9-18.6-23.4z"></path>
               </svg>
            </i>
            1300 393 733
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: We would need to see the DOM of the system you are testing, your code looks fine (other than using `Thread.Sleep()` right before `wait.until`) so it's difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the page you are testing.

Comment: @dooberrywotsit can you share the session link for the same?

Comment: @Christine I updated the question with the html. sorry for the slow response getting back